# Parsing json with Javascript throwing Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, typeerror

I am parsing the following JSON in Javascript

```
{"success":{"id_user":"1",
"username":"nasir",
"password":"f30aa7a662c728b7407c54ae6bfd27d1"}}
```

I have parsed the json like this

```
var obj = JSON.parse(result);  // result is the above json
console.log(obj.success);      // this shows the json in the console
```

but when i try to read the json element username by doing this

```
console.log("testing "+obj.success[0].username);
```

i get the following error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined

I have tried so many ways of doing this but not having luck, any suggestions where im going wrong .

Thanks

Comment: The object doesn't have an array anywhere so just remove the `[0]`.

Comment: Although the error message doesn't match with the code so I doubt you're showing your actual code.

Comment: And I strongly suggest not using MD5 to hash passwords. (e.g. http://md5.gromweb.com/?md5=f30aa7a662c728b7407c54ae6bfd27d1)

Comment: @Juhana maybe it IS the password itself. That's my kind of password. I however do not disclose them in public :-)

Comment: We need to see more of your code. As you describe it what you're doing is fine. So your problem must lie in something you have yet to share. Try building a fiddle to reproduce your problem, and read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hi Thanks for the suggestions, removing the [ ] worked,  i overlooked that, im still learning javascript, im sure this question will be usefull for other newbies, downvoting is a bit unfair :-(

Comment: Now that you've edited the question to include the *working* code, it doesn't make much sense. If you get your code working, post it as an answer or mark a correct answer, don't edit the question!

Comment: ok i have reverted the question to how it was

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
obj.success['username']
```

You cannot access objects like arrays. You need to give the name of the key.

Comment: Given `a={username:"bob"}` there's no difference between `a.username` and `a['username']`

Comment: Obviously i know that.The question was edited. It was first `object.success[0]` instead of  `object.success.username`. And when i started writing it there were no comments either but as soon as i posted. Boom four comments and the question has been also edited.

Comment: I hear you, I must have commented after the edit. This isn't a great question. I suggest you delete your answer, given it is no longer relevant, and downvote the question.

Comment: Unfortunately answers that have been marked correct can't be self-deleted.

Comment: Now the OP has edited it back! Your answer makes sense now. I will remove my downvote for your answer. But the downvote for the question itself remains.

Comment: Ah sorry my downvote cannot be changed. I read your answer in the context of the edited question, not the original question, as I suspect did everyone else who has downvoted you.

Comment: thats abit unfair sifiriday this will be usefull to javascript newbies , if i came across this question it would of helped me and saved a couple of hours and as my problem has been resolved by the suggestions in this post, it has been useful to me and im sure it will help someone else too. i thought stackoverflow was here to  support new programmers

Comment: @sifriday My badluck.

Comment: @n4zg While you are right that it might help some newbies but it is not a great question after all. I am sure there are many variants of this question already present on stack overflow. But the down votes on the question were unnecessary. A simple comment should have sufficed.I am a stack overflow newbie and seems like we both need to learn some implicit rules of the community.

Comment: Now I've unpicked everything what messed all this up was the editing of the question to reflect the answer. I think that's lead to all the downvotes - eg my comment about it being a bad question was in context of a nonsensical answer. Once you reverted the question it made more sense. You're right that there's no problem with newbie questions, SO is a great place to help newbies get started! I feel like we need to appeal to a mod to tidy this all up, but I am not sure of the best channel to do that (I am still relatively also a newbie to SO).

Comment: ah there we go - I just made a minor edit to the answer, and that allowed me to remove my downvote. I also removed my downvote from the question.